# Why does SaveFileDialog change the file name when it contains Korean characters?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filenames, savefiledialog

I'm using a `SaveFileDialog` for my application:

```csharp
private SaveFileDialog _saveFileDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
```

```csharp
if (_saveFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    _sSavePath = _saveFileDlg.FileName;
    _strReportData._sFilePath = _sSavePath;
    // --- do export report
}
```

As shown in the images below, after selecting a file with a Korean language name and clicking the `Save` button the last character of the file name is moved to the beginning; this does not happen when clicking the `Enter` button.

[image: SaveFileDialog with a file with Korean characters in its name selected. The last character in the name is highlighted for attention.]

[image: The same SaveFileDialog from the previous image after clicking the Save button. The last character in the file name has been moved to the beginning of the name.]

Comment: just Korean language have problem...English is ok..can help me?

Comment: dig the way of using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`

Comment: if (_saveFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
_sSavePath = _saveFileDlg.FileName;
_strReportData._sFilePath = _sSavePath;
panel1.Visible = true;
int iParam = 0;
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1000, 1000);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ExportExcelXLSX), iParam);
}

Comment: now i use ThreadPool..but useless

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_CurrentUICulture   Read this. You should change your UI thread culture firstly. And I have no idea what does your ThreadPool part of code really need for.  Also, maybe, this link also will be helpful - http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/01/11/1449754.html

Comment: Surely you are doing battle with the IME (Input Method Editor) that you need to use to enter Korean characters.  They are composed from multiple keystrokes, one radical per stroke.  The IME tries to be smart about detecting when you're done composing the character.  That didn't seem to work out quite correctly in this case.  You are much more likely to find somebody that understands the IME behavior well enough at [this site](https://korean.stackexchange.com/).